# Getting numbers from array which are not repeating

Tags: php

Im having troubles with solving one problem.

I have an array which contains numbers from 0 to 555.

```
array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4... 555)
```

I need a function which will return only those numbers which doesnt contain the same number.

So, the numbers like those will not be in return

11 - because '1' is repeating
255 - because 255 is repeating.. and so..

How should i solve this via php?

thank you

Comment: With code. [Where is yours?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: I have not tried, because i dont have ideas how to solve.

Comment: Do the repeating digits have to be consecutive, or should it also remove `101`?

Comment: `$result = array_filter($myArray, function($value) { $c = str_split($value); return count($c) == count(array_unique($c)); });`

Comment: Write a regular expression that matches numbers with no repeating digits (do a google search and you'll find this). Then use `array_filter` to match those numbers.

Comment: it should remove 101 because digit 1 is repeating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this is actually quite simple if you look at the numbers as a string. The function you could use is [count_chars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count-chars.php), which counts the number of occurrences of the characters in a string:

```
$array = array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 11, 255, 555);

$result = array_filter($array, function ($number) {

    $containsUniqueNumbers = true;

    foreach (count_chars(strval($number), 1) as $count) {

        // If any of the characters in the string occurs more than once:
        if ($count > 1) {
             $containsUniqueNumbers = false;
             break;
        }
    }

    return $containsUniqueNumbers;
});
```

The variable  `$result` will now contain `array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out, What I did is, Foreach value, turn the value into an array, then for that particular array, use the `array_unique()` function to remove duplicate entries, in this step, if there are duplicate entries then the size of the output will be less than the original string, and so we can use the sizeof function to check the size, and if they are not equal, then we can remove that value from the array.

```
<?php 
$sample = array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4... 555);

foreach ($sample as $key => $value) {
    if ($value > 9){
        //Do this for value more than 2 digits
        $original = str_split($value); 
        $check = array_unique($original); 
        if(sizeof($check)!= $original){
            //Remove the value
            unset($sample[$key]);

        }
    }
}

print_r($sample);

?>
```